# How to change value from select dropdown in database

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

i want to change value from my dropdown but i'm begginer and i'm little lost.
[image]

This is my Controller method:

```
 public function changeStatus(Request $request)
{
    $lead = Lead::find($request->id);

    $lead = array(
        'status_id' => $request->status_id
    ); 
    Lead::whereId($request->id)->update($lead);
    return redirect()->back()
        ->with(['toast' => ['message' => 'Lead Status updated successfully !']]);
}
```

This is my dropdown in vuejs file:

```
<select v-model="lead.status_id"  @change="onChanges()" class="form-select form-control">
                                        <option  v-for="status in statuses"
                                                 :value="status.id"
                                                 :key="status.id"
                                        >
                                            {{ status.status_name }}
                                         </option>

                                    </select>
```

and this is my method in vue js:

```
        onChanges(id,status_id) {
        this.$inertia.post(
            route("changestatus",{
                id:id,
                status_id:status_id,

            }),
        );
    },
```

the route is fine, the problem are probably my methods.

Comment: so what is the actual problem?'

Comment: Please describe where is the problem, does you fetch request in route ? Ajax URL is good ? What PHP framework are you using ?

Comment: The value remain the same when i select somethin else.array:                                       1 [▼
  "status_id" => null
]

Comment: Can you put your request dump here ?

Comment: i'm using laravel and inertia js with vue js

Comment: this is my dd($lead).           array:1 [▼
  "status_id" => null
]

Comment: @change="onChanges()" maybe you should pass variable here ? something like
@change="onChanges(status.id, status.id)"  ?

Comment: I'm stuck here i dont know what to pass and probably my vue js method is bad.

Comment: Try to pass some dummy hardcoded values to check If this is the issue: 
@change="onChanges(1,1)", and then check your request dump :)

Comment: Its changed bro.array:1 [▼
  "status_id" => "1"
]i tried this @change="onChanges(1,1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass right values to your onChanges method.
When you use @change="onChanges()" you should call it with the same parameters as it was declared - id and status_id.

So it should be something like this

```
@change="onChanges(lead.id, $event)"
```

And in js

```
  onChanges(id,event) {
    var status_id = event.target.value;
    this.$inertia.post(
        route("changestatus",{
            id:id,
            status_id:status_id,

        }),
    );
```

Comment: I think my values in vue js method onChanges() are wrong.I'm not sure how to pass the right ones.

Comment: this are my props:    props: {
        users: Object,
        filters: Object,
        leads: Object,
        errors: Object,
        statuses: Array,
        sources: Object,
        countries: Object,
    },

Comment: Do you have this project in public access? It would be faster to chat directly

Comment: check my this comment  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550403/how-to-change-value-from-select-dropdown-in-database/70550514?noredirect=1#comment124713777_70550403

Comment: I created room to chat, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240635/andrew-94,
you can join it, I send you an invitation